# Saving ExifInterface tags throws IOException

Tags: java, android, image, exif, ioexception

I want to use Exif tags for images.
It is very simple to read the tags and it works fine but saving not.

```
private void saveTag(String tag, String value) {
    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
        exif.setAttribute(tag, value);
        exif.saveAttributes();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        toast("Image no longer exists!");
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        toast("No image loaded!");
    }
}
```

Everytime, it throws IOException, what should I do?

granted:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: You should check what image path is. You might be using File.getAbsolutePath() which does not reference to physical file.

Comment: I chosen an image by intent, got URI, converted to path, reading TAG_DATETIME works by using that path but saving not

Comment: That's the problem. You are not having a path with file://, you are getting one with content://. Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46442700/writing-exif-data-to-image-saved-with-documentfile-class).

Comment: I am getting this image-path (external sd card):
/storage/500A-7363/DCIM/100ANDRO/DSC_0592.JPG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that picture must be located in device's storage when opening in Exif Interface. Have to copy picture from SD card to device's storage first.